# Parsing multi-line warnings in console output

Tags: errors, warnings

I am writing a parser for warnings.
I have extended the width of LaTeX's output so that errors and warnings all occur on a single line.

However, I have a problem with multi-line, *formatted* warn warnings as these are more difficult to handle.

An example is the following:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'kannan_random_1997':
(biblatex)                - Datamodel: Entry 'kannan_random_1997' 
(bibliography.bib): Invalid ISSN in value of field 'issn'.
```

Here I would like to remove the newline, the `(biblatex)` and the white-space after it so the warning appears on a single line such as the following:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues with 'kannan_random_1997': - Datamodel: Entry 'kannan_random_1997' Invalid ISSN in value of field 'issn'.
```

Is there a way of cutting down the output like the above, either by using LaTeX or by changing environment variables/parameters?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{asdf}\selectfont
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you paste a self-contained example document that reproduces the error(s) you want to extract? I presume `biblatex` errors are not the only ones your want to fetch?

Comment: probably `\def\MessageBreak{}` but untested as you provide no test code

Comment: note the latex2e message linebreak specifically puts the package name on each new line so that it's easier to parse these messages and recognise the continuation lines,...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  `\def\MessageBreak{}` doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: ah no you'd have to patch `\GenericWarning` where it locally defines `\messageBreak`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/asdf/m/n' undefined using `OT1/cmr/m/n' ins
tead on input line 12.
```

from

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericWarning}[2]{%
   \begingroup
      \def\MessageBreak{ }%^^J#1}%
      \set@display@protect
      \immediate\write\@unused{^^J#2\on@line.^^J}%
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \fontfamily{asdf}\selectfont
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
```